# IMAP Search - Date Range

Tags: php, imap

I am currently working on a bespoke system where i need to loop through an `IMAP` email account where the emails im looking for need lay within a `date` range.

As it stands, i have a working `IMAP` search function which is getting all emails with a certain string in the subject, the part which i cannot seem to find any documentation for, is the `BETWEEN` date range. I have seen that you can use the `BEFORE` `ON` & `SINCE` criteria but this doesn't seem to allow me to create a range as such.

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to mailbox: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" ON "'.$date.'"');
```

Im not asking for a complete spoonfeed but a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
Lewis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For those interested: After staring at the documentation for `imap_search` for about 10 minutes, i decided to try using both `SINCE` and `BEFORE` together. I managed to get the following code to do exactly what was required.

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" SINCE "'.$dateMonth.'" BEFORE "'.$date.'"');
```